# Using Coldfusion Builder and the Mercurial Eclipse plugin, how can you check in changes - including those in linked folders

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, mercurial, coldfusionbuilder

We have a Hg repository set up for the root of our webserver. There are a number of projects which have their own directories and there is a common C directory for components.

In CFBuilder, I have a project set up for each of them and I'm using linked folders to make it easier to access the components.

CFBuilder and the plugin correctly show that both are under version control, and update properly when changes are made -- but when select that I want to commit from the Project > Team > Commit, none of the changes from the C directory are shown in the changes which will be committed.

Is it possible to have it work this way, or is there a preferred way to work with linked folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a separate project for the Components, and do your commits from there. Changes made in your linked folders should be reflected in the C project, but if the C project is part of a different repository (which it would seem is the case, given your linked folders), you'll need to commit from that project.

Comment: the c directory contains the components from all of our projects, so there isn't really a 'owner' of that directory unless we have a 'parent' project that contains all of the projects... Still hoping for some type of Eclipse magic ;)

Comment: But aren't your components stored in a repo somewhere?

Comment: We're starting over... wanting to design our development workflow the 'right' way. At this point, it seems like your suggestion is really it. Thanks.